# Shift from Vimeo player to Videojs Player

Tags: javascript, video.js, vimeo-player

I have developed an application that uses vimeo player to play videos.
Now I want to use locally hosted videos instead of vimeo.
I tried to convert my code to make use of videojs player instead of vimeo player.
But I didn't worked for me.
Is there any way, I can play locally hosted video using vimeo player? So I dont have to change code.
Are there any guide to help me convert from vimeo to videojs.
I am confused in video events and methods that need to translated.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use Vimeo for self hosted videos. Video.js API docs are here: https://docs.videojs.com/ This question isn't a great fit for SO, you'll get a better response breaking it down into specific actionable questions.

Comment: @misterben i will edit question to add specific conversion issues that i am facing.